# How to find a class tagged with postsharp aspect via reflection

Tags: reflection, postsharp

I tryout some ways to use postsharp

The definition of one of my custom aspects looks like:

```
<Serializable> _
<MulticastAttributeUsage(PersistMetaData:=True)> _
Public Class StringChecker
    Inherits LocationInterceptionAspect

    Public Overrides Sub OnGetValue(ByVal args As LocationInterceptionArgs)
        MyBase.OnGetValue(args)
        ..... ..... .....
```

When I try to find all classes that are tagged with the attribute / aspect , the result ist always empty.
I use this code to discover the assemblys at runtime:

```
Dim targetClasses As IEnumerable(Of Type) = From asm In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(Function(A) A.FullName.Contains("MyNameSpace")) _
                                                .SelectMany(Function(A) A.GetTypes()) _
                                                .Where(Function(T) T.IsDefined(GetType(StringChecker), True))
```

When I use for testing proposals, a normal atttribute, the query delivers the espected types.
Hoppefully some can give me a hint what I have to do.

edit: It looks like the custom attributes can only be found in the class propertys..

Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Use [ReflectionSearch](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_reflectionsearch) but it does not retrieve aspects added with IAspectProvider.
2. Use [IAspectRepositoryService](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_iaspectrepositoryservice)

Comment: Hello Gael, thank you for your quick response. In your documentation for ReflectionSearch I found a hint that is only useable at compile time - is that right?